# In a vector space in finite dimension, all vectors which are not colinear, are orthogonal. True or false?

Tags: vector-spaces

This is a theorem I learn few month ago, and I found it funny. Well I found on facebook, some groups about mathematics, and just to test people I said :

> In a vector space in finite dimension, all vectors which are not co-linear, are orthogonal. True or false ?

And each time it was a fifty fifty between people who agreed and others. Then I think here maths level is higher than in these groups, can you tell me if the demonstration I have is true or false?

---

**I just precise before, than english is not my mother tongue, and I will maybe make some maths vocabulary mistakes (and english too)**

---

**Proof :** 
All free familly of vectors can be completed as a base. All basis $(e_1,...,e_n)$ can be consider as an orthogonal (or orthonormal if base's vectors are unit vectors) base for the choice of one dot product. Then define a different dot product for each bases of the vector space. QED

Obviously the theorem is false in an euclidian space...

---

So what do you think, are my maths teachers in the truth ? I hope my translation is correct.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I don't undersand the "translation request" part of your question, since there is no original language quote.

Comment: My translation request is just because I may did some english mistakes :)

Comment: Since we don' have the original text, you should remove the tag. You can still try to explain more in details your issue (there is a statement, a proof which does not seem to fit...).

Comment: So the two vectors $(1,1)$ and $(1,0)$, not being collinear, are orthogonal?

Comment: Yes if you define a special dot product just for them !

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Not with the usual dot product.

Comment: The question is reasonable. Your answer is bizarre. If you have $n+1$ mutually non-colinear vectors in an $n$-dimensional space, no matter when you decide to define an inner product, you cannot have them all be orthogonal.

Comment: One should note that the notion of orthogonality requires an inner product space, and that is not part of the premise. - Likewise one might claim that given any finite set (having at least three elements) any two elements of it are inverse to each other and argue that one can definie a suitable group structure on that set

Comment: So if the vector space does not have an inner product, then _no_ vectors are orthogonal, but any two vectors can be _made_ orthogonal by imposing a suitable inner product on the vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sentence is neither true nor false, because it has no meaning:

> In a vector space in finite dimension, all vectors which are not collinear, are orthogonal.

Collinearity and orthogonality are not properties of vectors; 
it is meaningless to say that a vector $v$ is collinear or that
another vector $u$ is orthogonal.
There is no such thing as "all vectors which are not collinear".

A *set* of vectors can be said to be collinear or orthogonal.
(I think this would generally be understood to mean
pairwise collinear or pairwise orthogonal.)
So we could decide the truth value of a statement such as this:

> In a vector space in finite dimension, all *sets of* vectors which are not collinear, are orthogonal.

This is false for any dimension greater than $1$;
take any two non-collinear vectors $u$ and $v$ in the vector space, and then
the set $\{u,v,2v\}$ is neither collinear (on account of $u$ and $v$) nor orthogonal (on account of $v$ and $2v$) regardless of the definition
of the inner product.

The following statement is true:

> In a vector space in finite dimension, any pair of vectors that are not
>   collinear are orthogonal under a suitably chosen inner product.

In other words, given non-collinear vectors $u$ and $v$, there is
*some* inner product under which those two vectors are orthogonal.
This is what the "proof" in the question actually shows.

But there is no single inner product space in which every pair of
vectors is either collinear or orthogonal.
Given an inner product space and two vectors $u$ and $v$ that are orthogonal
in that vector space, $u+v$ is also a vector and $\{u,u+v\}$ are
neither collinear nor orthogonal.
So this statement is false:

> In a vector space in finite dimension with inner product
>   $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, 
>   any pair of vectors that are not collinear are orthogonal.

The statement about Euclidean space in the question is an example of this.

Comment: Its exactly why I took a translation request, now you have translate me the theorem as I understood it. Its just I don't speak english as well as i want . Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The question simply doesn't make sense as stated, which might explain the disagreement on Facebook: One can only speak of orthogonality of vectors in a vector space when the space is endowed with an inner product. The "proof" is anyway an argument for the following:

> For any linearly independent set $S$ of vectors in a f.d. vector space $\Bbb V$, there is some inner product on $\Bbb V$ with respect to which the vectors in $S$ are pairwise orthogonal.

Likewise, it doesn't make sense to say that this result fails for Euclidean space, because by definition the term *Euclidean* entails a fixed inner product. (of course, the statement is true for the vector space $\Bbb R^n$ underlying the Euclidean space $(\Bbb R^n, \langle\,\cdot\, , \,\cdot\,\rangle)$).

Comment: So if I take a vector space with just a,b and c as vectors then I  define threedifferents dot prod in such a way that (a,b)=0 ((a,c))=0 <b,c>=0 i'm wrong ?

Comment: Wrong about what? Again, the original true-false question doesn't even make sense as written.

Comment: I don't undertand what it doesn't make sense... you take all possible basis of the vector space, and for each of them you use Gram-Schimdt process then you find orthogonal basis. ?

Comment: The word "orthogonal" is not defined for vector spaces, so the question uses undefined terminology, and must be modified before it makes sense. Your argument is valid if you replace "all vectors that are not collinear are orthogonal" with "for every pair of vectors that are not collinear, there is an inner product for which they are orthogonal".

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a problem of how you make the statement.

If you ask

> In a vector space in finite dimension, all vectors which are not linearly dependent, are orthogonal?

it means that you **already** have an inner product, it doesn't have sense to say 'orthogonal' in other case, so, IMHO this is just a funny puzzle, everyone would answer *NO* but you have a nice (but incorrect) argument to argue that the answer is *YES*.

Comment: But if you _already_ have an inner product, then there are pairs of vectors that are neither collinear nor orthogonal. Given an arbitrary pair of non-collinear vectors you can "make" them orthogonal, but first you may have to remove the old inner product and define a new inner product, and after you have done this there still will be other pairs of vectors that are neither collinear nor orthogonal.

Comment: @DavidK So, are you arguing that the process of creating a new inner product such that a *given* set of linearly independent vectors is orthogonal can not be performed?

Comment: Actually I think I'm agreeing with your answer. Of course, given any set of linearly independent vectors you can always define a new inner product that will make them orthogonal, but then simultaneously you make some other sets of linearly independent vectors _not_ orthogonal.

Comment: @DavidK Exactly! So, in conclusion, the proposition is **always** false, in some sense: once you fix an inner product, there will always be non-orthogonal linearly independent sets of vectors (with more than one vector).